# Unity C# What does the funtion Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded(String string) do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in the ARFoundation Unity samples I found the following code snippet:

```
public void BackButtonPressed()
        {
            if (Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded("Menu"))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu", LoadSceneMode.Single);
                LoaderUtility.Deinitialize();
            }
        }
```

Can somebody please explain to me when and why to use Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded(String string)? In the Unity docs I found this as explanation: Can the streamed level be loaded?

But that tells me nothing.

And when and why should one also use `LoadSceneMode.Single` and `LoaderUtility.Deinitialize()`?
I found this for `LoaderUtility.Deinitialize()`: Deinitializes the currently active XR Loader, if one exists. This destroys all subsystems.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded` does exactly what you think it should do when reading the function name, it checks if the streamed level can be loaded. Use it **BEFORE** attempting to actually load a streamed level. Streamed in this case means downloading the level for the WebGL client.
The progress of the stream means how far the download of your level has progressed.

Use this function to check the download state, just like you see in the doc example, to prevent an exception when trying to load an unfinished level.

Behind the scenes it uses a float called `downloadProgress` of the `UnityWebRequest` to determine if the file is downloaded.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-downloadProgress.html

Deeper down you will most probably find a FileStream, hence the name of the function.

Comment: Ok, but what is meant by level here? And is that only important for WebGL clients but not for other platforms and why should one even download anything cuz I'm only trying to load/change the scene and that scene which is loaded is always within the project.

I'm really sorry if my questions sound dumb. I'm relatively new to Unity/ARFoundation. And thanks for your comment! I really do appreciate that!